# pass a parameter to my loaded div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a few html pages that share the same navbar. Therefore I wrote one html file - topnav.html and I used the following jQuery code to load it into every page.

**javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {        
    $('#topnav').load('topnav.html');
});
</script>
```

**html**

```
<body>
<div id="topnav"></div>
...
```

Now, I discovery each page need to have different properties (say different titles). How can I pass the title parameter to the tapnav.html page?

Answer (score 0):

This first solution is in PHP, because I like it much better. If you want to do it in JS, see the edit below.

If you are using PHP, you can include a file (with functions), and pass the function as a parameter, like so:

**index.php**

```
<?php
    include "topnav.php";
    top("title");
?>
```

**topnav.php**

```
<?php
    function top($title) {
?>
    <div id="topNav">
        <!-- Other code you need here -->
        <span id="title"><?= $title ?></span> <!-- put in inputted title -->
    </div>
<?php
    }
?>
```

I don't use JS/jQuery to load resources (parts of pages) for my websites. PHP `include()` is much more convenient and I use it all the time!

---

**EDIT**

Now that I think about it, you could probably do a very similar thing in JavaScript, although it's slightly more cumbersome. Put a function in the JS, and just call it from the page.

For example:

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {        
        $('#topnav').load('topnav.html');
        $("body").append(top("title"));
    });
</script>
```

**topnav.html**

```
<script>
    // basically return (or print out) string of resource
    function top(title) {
        return "<div id='topNav'>" +
                   "<!-- Other code you need here -->" +
                   "<span id='title'>" + title + "</span>" +
                "</div>";
    }
</script>
```

**EDIT** 2: More detailed explanation (by request)

What the JS example does is load the resource file like you did in your example. However, instead of it being a plain HTML file like yours, it is a JS file. Once you've loaded it, you now can use the JS script. Basically the added script allows you to use a mostly-predefined string, but you can add some variables (for example, `"<span id='title'>" + title + "</span>"` allows you to put `title` into it).

Comment: thanks for the answer. I don't use php. I kind got what you say in the case of javascript. Could you share a more detailed example please?

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's brilliant explanation. I actually want to pass the title and then use it in a <a> tag as the link. e.g. I pass 'example' as title. Then one <a>'s href property changes to href="example.html". How can I do that?

Comment: Then just change the function return string to include `"<a href='" + title + ".html'>"`.

Comment: have you tried this? Your topnav.html contains js code. Do you think $('#topnav').load('topnav.html') will work?

Comment: No I haven't tried it, but HTML can definitely include `<script>` tags. If it doesn't work for you, then tell me.